# Calculating confidence interval using "ci" function

Tags: r, group-by, confidence-interval

I have a set of data and besides finding the average of columns for each group, I want to find a
confidence interval. the sample data is shown below:

```
id <- c(1101:1108)
age <- c(12,15,14,12,3,1,2,5)
length <- c(52,62,63,58,79,45,65,25)
result <- c("TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE","TRUE","FALSE")
data<-data.frame(id, age, length, result)


    id age length result
1 1101  12     52   TRUE
2 1102  15     62  FALSE
3 1103  14     63   TRUE
4 1104  12     58  FALSE
5 1105   3     79   TRUE
6 1106   1     45  FALSE
7 1107   2     65   TRUE
8 1108   5     25  FALSE
```

what I want to do is calculating the average and 0.95 confidence interval for the length parameter for each group of the result, so I used the code below:

```
g <- data %>% select(length,result) %>% group_by(result) %>% summarise(Ave_length=mean(length, na.rm=TRUE))
```

and to calculate the confidence interval for each group, I used the following function from `gmodels` package

```
ci(data$length[data$result=="TRUE"], 0.95)
ci(data$length[data$result=="TRUE"], 0.95)
```

Howveer, what I got is an warning message " Warning message:
In ci.numeric(data$length[data$result == "TRUE"], 0.95) :
No class or unkown class.  Using default calcuation."

Do you have any suggestion on how I can fix this? or is there any other function I can use to calculate the confidence interval

Comment: It is a warning message and not an error

Comment: @akrun thanks, I edited my question, still with this warning, can I trust the result it produces?

Comment: it is just that there are different methods for `ci` i.e. `methods('ci')` and it couldn't find the `class` of the data, so it is using the default option for `ci.numeric`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is nothing to worry about the `warning` message.

```
methods('ci')
#[1] ci.binom      ci.estimable* ci.lm*        ci.lme*       ci.numeric*
```

If we check the source code, it starts with a `warning` without any check.

```
getAnywhere('ci.numeric')
function (x, confidence = 0.95, alpha = 1 - confidence, na.rm = FALSE, 
    ...) 
{
    warning("No class or unkown class.  Using default calcuation.") ####
    est <- mean(x, na.rm = na.rm)
    stderr <- sd(x, na.rm = na.rm)/sqrt(nobs(x))
    ci.low <- est + qt(alpha/2, nobs(x) - 1) * stderr
    ci.high <- est - qt(alpha/2, nobs(x) - 1) * stderr
    retval <- c(Estimate = est, `CI lower` = ci.low, `CI upper` = ci.high, 
        `Std. Error` = stderr)
    retval
}
```

It is possible that the developers may change it in the future.  Also, there are some typos `unkown` instead of `unknown`

It means that `numeric` class `vector`s are getting this warning

```
ci(rnorm(10))
#  Estimate   CI lower   CI upper Std. Error 
# 0.3754708 -0.2600370  1.0109787  0.2809300 
#Warning message:
#In ci.numeric(rnorm(10)) :
#  No class or unkown class.  Using default calcuation.
```

---

This issue seems to be showing only for `numeric` class.  If we apply the `ci` on a `lm` model (`ci.lm`)

```
ci(lm(Sepal.Length ~ Species, iris))
#                  Estimate  CI lower CI upper Std. Error       p-value
#(Intercept)          5.006 4.8621258 5.149874 0.07280222 1.134286e-113
#Speciesversicolor    0.930 0.7265312 1.133469 0.10295789  8.770194e-16
#Speciesvirginica     1.582 1.3785312 1.785469 0.10295789  2.214821e-32
```

as `ci.lm` doesn't have the `warning` at the beginning

```
getAnywhere('ci.lm')
function (x, confidence = 0.95, alpha = 1 - confidence, ...) 
{
    x <- summary(x)
    est <- coef(x)[, 1]
    ci.low <- est + qt(alpha/2, x$df[2]) * coef(x)[, 2]
    ci.high <- est - qt(alpha/2, x$df[2]) * coef(x)[, 2]
    retval <- cbind(Estimate = est, `CI lower` = ci.low, `CI upper` = ci.high, 
        `Std. Error` = coef(x)[, 2], `p-value` = coef(x)[, 4])
    retval
}
```

Possible reason is that the `ci` methods are primarily checking for `lm` or `lme` `class` etc. and if none of them are found, it is switching to default mode with `ci` for `numeric` class and the `warning` is kind of misleading in that respect